# Is this an F# bug?

Tags: f#, interface, ienumerable

I have an type that is implementing `IEnumerable<T>` interface, all is ok:

```
open System

type Bar() =

     interface Collections.IEnumerable with
         member x.GetEnumerator () = null

     interface Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int> with
         member x.GetEnumerator () = null
```

But things goes wrong if type inherits `IEnumerable` interface implementation via the base type:

```
open System

type Foo() =
     interface Collections.IEnumerable with
         member x.GetEnumerator () = null

type Bar() =
     inherit Foo()

     interface Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int> with
         member x.GetEnumerator () = null
```

Code above produces the type inference errors:

- `The member 'GetEnumerator<'a0 when 'a0 : null> : unit -> 'a0 when 'a0 : null' does not have the correct type to override any given virtual method`
- `The member 'GetEnumerator<'a0 when 'a0 : null> : unit -> 'a0 when 'a0 : null' does not have the correct number of method type parameters. The required signature is 'GetEnumerator : unit -> Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<int>'.`

Am I doing something wrong or this is an F# compiler bug?

`Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.30319.1`

---

**Update** more canonical example:

```
type IFoo     = abstract Bar : obj list
type IFoo<'a> = abstract Bar : 'a  list
                inherit IFoo
/* ok */
type Foo        = interface IFoo      with member x.Bar = []
                  interface IFoo<Foo> with member x.Bar = []
/* fail */
type FooBase    = interface IFoo      with member x.Bar = []
type FooDerived = interface IFoo<Foo> with member x.Bar = [] // <---
                  inherit FooBase
/*
 error FS0017: The member 'get_Bar : unit -> 'a list' does not
    have the correct type to override any given virtual method.
*/
```

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, this is just an type inference fail because of F# may implement inherited interface members in the derived interface implementation declaration:

```
type IA = abstract A : int
type IB = inherit IA
type IC = inherit IB

type Baz =
     interface IC with
       member x.A = 1
```

So in my example I should specify the correct return type explicitly because `member x.GetEnumerator()` in derived `Bar` type may match both `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` and `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: Just figured that out, too ;) Yes, the problem is that the type of the GetEnumerable is ambigous if not specified explicitly as both IEnumerable and IEnumerable<'a> specifiy such a method.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler cannot infer the correct type from your "null"-implementation. Try

```
open System

type Foo() =
     interface Collections.IEnumerable with
         member x.GetEnumerator () = null

type Bar() =
     inherit Foo()

     interface Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int> with
         member x.GetEnumerator () : Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<int> = null
```

*UPDATE:*
The reason is, that the type of the `GetEnumerator` method implemented by the `Bar` type is ambigous as `IEnumerable<'a>` implements/inherits the non-generic `IEnumerable` which also specifies a (non-generic) `GetEnumerator` method. So, how should the compiler infer, which method exactly you are trying to implement if all he gets is null? Therefore we need a type annotation in this case.

Comment: ok, lets take an interface like this: `type Foo<'a> = abstract M : unit -> 'a` and try to implement it without specifying any types except required in declaration: `type Bar() = interface Foo<string> with member x.M() = null` - it works perfectly well!

Comment: Sure, but that's not the same. An equivalent sample would rather read `type Boo<'a> = abstract M : 'a` and `type Foo<'a> = abstract M : unit -> Boo<'a>` and finally `type Bar() = interface Foo<string> with member x.M() = null`. Again, the compiler cannot infer Boo<_> (like IEnumerator<_>).

Comment: Hm, you're right, but what about first example? How the correct type is inferred there?

Comment: Sorry, I take back what I said in my last comment. The sample actually works if you allow `Boo<'a>` to be null using the `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` attribute. So, what does this mean? My answer somehow solves the problem, but I am not sure about the reason anymore...

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the fact, that `IEnumerable<_>` implements `IEnumerable` (non-generic). If you implement both interfaces explicitly for the `Bar` type, it also works without any type annotations in the case of inheriting from `Foo`.